# AES 128 ECB decryption nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

Encrypted data results as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amJwV.png)

now if i decrypt the result using Node.js

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt('HcMV322sPPrFonlvXZ5pvFpXABVrxYVAXrEr9vcu7TIFOPNQVGq5svEv3959sRDxkDHB/nav80iGMPBiz8bDeA==', 'my secretkey 123');

var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(originalText, '--->');
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDBJR.png)
results in empty string

Comment: got the solution 


let keyUtf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey)

ENC = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ENC, keyUtf8, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,  keySize: 128 });

ENC = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(ENC).toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let keyUtf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey)

ENC = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ENC, keyUtf8, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,  keySize: 128 });

ENC = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(ENC).toString();
```

Comment: please add a small description

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.